# Ventana de alerta con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5

¿Habrá una función ya predefinida que me permita arrojar un mensaje de alerta sin que interrumpa el flujo de la pagina web?

Acontece que construí un web server con un esp32 el cual procesa señales de sensores y las grafica en el servidor web, funciona todo correctamente pero quiero implementar un mensaje de alerta que salga cuando se supere un valor umbral, logré implementar el mensaje con la función window.alert() pero me detiene el flujo de la pagina, es decir que se para de graficar hasta que no le de a aceptar.

Necesito de una función que me mande un mensaje de alerta pero que no me detenga el flujo de la pagina. No soy muy diestro en JavaScript y el web server es básico, estaría agradecido por la ayuda.

Saludos

Comment: No existe una función nativa para ello, te recomiendo no utilizarlo cuando existen muchas opciones para mostrar mensajes tipo alert, te recomiendo usar sweetalert2

Comment: Puede que lo que estas buscando sean [`toast`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/toasts/), pero aun así SO no son bienvenidas las preguntas basadas en opiniones. 

Comment: Si solo quieres saber si existe esa funcion predecterminada la respuesta es nó, te recomiendo investigar una APIs que haga lo que quieres o hacerla tu mismo. @BrayanMartínezSantana No es una pregunta basada en opiniones, es una pregunta basada en recomendaciones, aunque es casi lo mismo.

Comment: Considera usar [*Notificaciones*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API). Después de obtener el permiso sólo es: `new Notification("Hola", {body:"El contenido del mensaje"})`.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

No hay forma de hacerlo a menos que tu la construyas desde un html, javascript como tal no lo hace, te recomiendo una libreria muy buena para alertas
[sweetalert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#download)